# Having trouble incrementing X axis by Month in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datejs

I am trying to create a graph in high charts where the plot interval is equal to a calendar month (varies per month). I am using date.js which has a function called addMonths which understands the different number of days in a month.

However I am having trouble converting this into something that highcharts understands (appears to be ms).

Does anybody know how I can get this simple POC code to have 1 month intervals on the x axis?

http://jsfiddle.net/uqv23bze/

```
$(function () {
var data = [];
var d = new Date();

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var x = new Date(d.addMonths(1));        
    data.push([x,i]);
}

$('#container').highcharts({ 
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Highcharts` support the `UTC` date format in `ms` as you said. `DateTime` can be converted using `Date.UTC` in javascript:

```
var date = new Date(d.addMonths(1));
var x = Date.UTC(date.getYear() + 1900, date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
```

Also you have to use `tickInterval` for `xAxis` to make sure the intervals are in months:

```
tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // (30 days, 24 hours, 3600 seconds, 1000 milliseconds)
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqv23bze/2/)